# iOS project: Static/Dynamic code analysis and call graphs

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-analysis, call-graph, dynamic-analysis

I am looking for some handy code analysis tools for iOS projects, esp. to do static analysis, dynamic analysis and generate call graphs. In my investigation so far, I found

- Dtrace as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749452/can-the-messages-sent-to-an-object-in-objective-c-be-monitored-or-printed-out/10749819#10749819) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790772/how-do-i-see-every-method-called-when-i-run-my-application-in-the-iphone-simulat)
- Clang as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670260/generating-call-graph-for-c-code?rq=1)
- Doxygen as explained [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~chanson9/tutorials/doxygen/doxygen.html)

Are there any other open source tools available for my case that I miss? Also has anyone tried any of the above ones successfully for objective-c iOS projects?

Thanks

Comment: after 2.5 years .. have u found anything ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you not satisfied yet with the built-in XCode analyzer (Product > Analyze)?

The primary author of LLVM project and Clang now works at Apple as the Director of Developer Tools Department. He's primarily responsible in embedding Clang to XCode.

So, I believe the analyzer within XCode already an excellent tool that you need to do analysis on your iOS project.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried XCode analyzer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Analyze/Analyze.html but I need a static/dynamic code analysis capability to know what methods call which others from where... A tool that can show the basic pathways of the method invocations would be awesome.